# VB.net Unhandled Exceptions Dialog / Log UnhandledException cannot be found

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In the course of tracking down another error for a project I came across a method to provide some feedback for unhandled exceptions.  I've followed the instructions from the original post, but it seems things might be a little different as of Visual Studio 2010.  What I'm tyring to do is either pop up a message box or write a log file for errors that occur in an application that where completely unexpected an unhandled.  I don't get them very often, but when I do my applications fail siliently.  Here's what I've got in the ApplicationEvents.vb file:

```
Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException

    MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString)
    e.ExitApplication = False

End Sub
```

The error I'm gettin now is `Statement is not valid in a namespace.` which completely makes sense.  It seems I need to place this in a class, so I tried placing the code in a public class named ErrorHandler and now I'm told `UnhandledException` cannot be found.  Is this a different property of Me now?  Or do I need to string up the UnhandledException myself somehow?  Or is there an entierly different and better way to approach this?

Comment: The workaround you attempted caused more problems than it solved.  You didn't post enough code but it looks from the error message that you forgot to put this method inside of a class.  It needs to be *inside* the MyApplication class.  Post the entire content of the ApplicationEvents.vb source file if that didn't help.

Comment: @HansPassant Please see the comments at the bottom of my code and the comments on the answer below.  I indicated that I realized the sub should be inside a class, and below you will see that when I open the ApplicationEvents.vb file it is blank in my projects in visual studio 2010.  I do not see the code Rowland Shaw has posted below, but after adding it my problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: Use the comboboxes at the top of the editor window to add events.

Comment: I'm familiar with that approach and checked there.  I don't see any available events in those combo boxes.  I swear to you I know (kind of) what I'm doing here, there is simply no code generated in that file by visual studio; for me.  I see that this is occasionally a problem for some other people based on my results from google.  I don't know if this is a known issue with 2010, or if there is just something amiss in my instalation. At any rate, the immediate matter is solved for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [quote MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.unhandledexception%28v=vs.99%29):

> The code for the UnhandledException event handler is stored in the ApplicationEvents.vb file, which is hidden by default.
>
> To access the Code Editor window for application events:
>
> 1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, click Properties on the Project menu.
> 2. Click the Application tab.
> 3. Click the View Application Events button to open the Code Editor.

When I follow these steps I get a file that looks a little like:

```
Namespace My

    ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    ' 
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    End Class

End Namespace
```

And I can add the event handler to that class

Comment: I might not have emphasized it enough but it's up there; the code described above is placed in the applicationevents.vb file, and that is how I accessed it.  What I'm still trying to make sense out of is why `Event 'UnhandledException' cannot be found.`

Comment: That's interesting... what version of Visual Studio are you using?  I get a blank module.  No Namespace, no partial friend class, no comments, nothing.  However, I can see from your example that I seem to be missing the `Namespace My` and `End Namespace` lines.  Putting those in took care of the issue.  Thank you.